# Is this a legit form of induction?

Tags: induction

I'm currently studying a proof in graph theory and it says:

'Suppose that what we want to prove is true for 1,2,3, ..., n-1. We will prove that it holds for n'. Is this a legit form of induction?

Usually, in the induction proofs I encountered until now it was something like. Suppose it's true for n, then we will prove it's true for n +1 or suppose it's true for n-1, we will prove that it's true for n but this seems to be another form induction than the one mentioned above.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  It is called complete induction.  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction):

> Another variant, called **complete induction**, **course of values induction** or **strong induction** (in contrast to which the basic form of induction is sometimes known as **weak induction**) makes the inductive step easier to prove by using a stronger hypothesis: one proves the statement $P(m+1)$ under the assumption that $P(n)$ holds for **all** natural $n$ less than $m+1$; by contrast, the basic form only assumes $P(m)$.

Answer (score 2):

It's also called strong induction. Notice this is perfectly fine. The idea is that since if the $n-1$ case were proved, it required proving the $n-2$ case which required proving the $n-3$ case, etc... all the way down to your base case, which you proved. You're just taking advantage of all your information.

Answer (score 1):

The induction is used to prove that

$$(\forall n\geq n_0)\;\;\; P_n$$

first, we check $P_{n_0}$.

secondly,

> weak induction

we say:

Let $n\geq n_0\;\;:\: P_n$

and we prove $P_{n+1}.$

> strong induction

we say:

let $n\geq n_0\;\;: P_{n_0};P_{n_0+1},...P_n$

and we prove $P_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very corect. For example, view https://nrich.maths.org/4718.
Good luck!